# WSO2-IS 5.11.0 - Edit Resident Identity Provider

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I've changed the external port of WSO2-IS docker container from 9443 to 9444 and now I want to edit the Resident IDP port of all services but I can't.

**Home -> Identity Providers -> Resident -> Inbound Authentication Configuration -> OAuth2/OpenID Connect Configuration**

[image]

How can I edit these ports?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These endpoints are deployed inside the identity server. So the ports of these services will be changed if you offset the product's port. Adding the following config on deployment.toml file will change the WSO-IS port from 9443(default)to 9444.

```
[server]
offset = "1"
```

Refer: https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/references/default-ports-of-wso2-products/#changing-the-offset-for-default-ports

Comment: I can't change by console? Some articles say to remove port's number on this page.